# jquery mobile with php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to learn jquery mobile and I was wondering if jquery mobile can be used with PHP as if I'm building a regular website?

with jquery mobile tags are almost the same, but they use tags such as data-role,

indext.html

```
<div data-role="header">
<div data-role="content">
content page
</div>
</div>
```

Can I do something like

index.html

```
<div data-role="header">
<div data-role="content">
<?php echo $content; //this content will be populated by mysql
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Or would I have to use ajax to get the content?

index.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(data){
    $('.page1').html(data);
  }
});
});


<div data-role="header">
<div data-role="content" class='page1'>
<?php echo $content; //this content will be populated by mysql
?>
</div>
</div>
```

test.html

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
while($q = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$content = $q['content'];
echo $content;
}
?>
```

Comment: The data attribute is just another html attribute and not a tag.

Comment: @PeeHaa icic. so there's no best or fast way to connect to mysql with php? I've seen people use try, exception... but I usually just use mysql queries and connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm trying to learn jquery mobile and I was wondering if jquery mobile can be used with PHP as if I'm building a regular website?

Of course. It *is* a regular website.

> with jquery mobile tags are almost the same, but they use tags such as data-role,

Those are attributes, not tags and are standard HTML 5 (insofar as HTML 5 is a standard, since it is still in draft form).

Even if they weren't standard, PHP wouldn't care. As far as it is concerned it is just outputting text.

Comment: would jquery mobile be more popular than using native language? such as objective C and java since there's programs out there now that can integrate jquery mobile into different SDKs?

Comment: or would it be different depending on what we're building? such as games and such?

Comment: @andrewliu: native code will (should) always run faster. However using a 'normal' website makes it a lot easier to maintain (especially for multi-platform) because most browsers (/engines) will render it (almost) the same.